# Enemy of an enemy relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm going through the book "How to prove it" by Velleman and I have come across the following question: "Let E = {(p, q) ∈ P × P | the person p is an enemy of the person q}, and F = {(p, q) ∈ P × P | the person p is a friend of the person q}, where P is the set of all people. What does the saying "an enemy of one’s enemy is one’s friend" mean about the relations E and F?"

In attempting to solve this problem I let E be the set {(J, M), (B, M)}. Where J, M and B are people named John, Bill and Mark. I assume this would then mean that E<sup>-1</sup> ∘ E = F. But the answer key gives a different solution:

E ∘ E ⊆ F (answer key)

While I agree that a subset of F is correct (one can have friends that are not enemies of enemies). I find the choice of E ∘ E peculiar, after some further reasoning this only seems to be true if both the pairs (J, M) and (M, J) are included. But it's certainly possible to be one's enemy without that being the opposite way around unless I am misunderstanding something here?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining $E^{-1}$ and $K\circ J$?

Comment: E^-1 is the inverse, K and J are not relationships but the first initial of a persons name.

Comment: In your example there simply is no enemy of an enemy since $M$ is nobody's enemy.

Comment: I think your answer is correct and the book is wrong unless the enemy relation is symmetrical.

Comment: In your case $E\circ E = \emptyset$ and it is correct.   $J$ is an enemy of $M$ and $B$ is an enemy of $M$ but no-one is enemies of $J$ or of $B$ so we can't put the statement to the test.  If we did a case with $E=\{(J,M), (M,B), (C,B)\}$, Then $E\circ E= \{J,B\}$ meaning that $J$ is a friend $B$ which works as $J$ is an enemy of $M$ who is an enemy of $B$.  So $B$ says "$J$ is an an enemy of my enemy so it my friend"

Comment: I think that $E^{-1}\circ E\subset F$ would corresponds to the statement "If you are an enemy of a person I am an enemy of you are my friend (and I am yours)".  In your example $E = \{(J, M),(B,M)\}$, $E^{-1}=\{(M,J),(M,B)\}$ and $E^{-1}\circ E= \{(J,J), (B,B)\}$ which need not be a subset of $F$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the clarifications this is still quite new for me so it's tricky. I'll read through the second part you posted a bit more but the first part is more clear now.

Comment: I have to admit the wording is unnatural and "backword sounding"  It probably *would* have been easy if it were written that $(p,q)$ meant $q$ is the enemy of $p$ rather than the other way around.  Although logically it *shouldn't* be any harder and as mathematicians we *must* be able to work with either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this follows directly, using the definition on page 173 in the second edition of the book you refer to:
By that definition we have
$$E\circ E:=\{(a,c)\in P\times P\mid\exists b\in P\colon (a,b)\in E\land(b,c)\in E\}$$
and this is exactly the relation "$a$ is an enemy of an enemy of $c$":

- Let $(a,c)\in E\circ E$, then $a$ is by definition an enemy of some $b\in P$ and $b$ is an enemy of $c$, so $a$ is an enemy of an enemy of $c$.
- Let $a$ be an enemy of an enemy of $c$. Call this enemy $b$. Then $(a,b)\in E$ and $(b,c)\in E$, hence $(a,c)\in E\circ E$.

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more the relationship still holds even if enemy or friends relationships don't go both ways, E∘E = {} in my example. Which is a subset of everything. And if it goes both ways then they are friends. This question seems a lot more tricky then I assumed.

Thanks for the swift answer.